# Initialize vector of hardcoded int for different platforms

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have a problem with an initialization of a vector of integers named `id_vector`that don't need to change.

the initializer is done like this:

```
static int id[4]{200,300,400,500};
id_vector = std::vector<int> (id,id + (sizeof(id)/sizeof(int)));
```

So far so good. but now we need to have different versions of this software, and I would like to choose a different id array depending on the version. The only way I can think of is to do it inside a `#ifdef`or some sort of macro, but I was wondering if someone knows a better way to do it. 
I was thinking something like a namespace but I don't know if this is a good use for it.

**UPDATE**

Had a typo in the code, sorry about that. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear but basically this is a list of valid ids and there are two versions that need different valid ids. Don't think is necessary to add more code.

Comment: How can we say without knowing anything about your build environments, whether the different versions already have different executable images (and whether that's desirable or undesirable) or just differ in included libraries / config etc.?  You could use a namespace but you'd then need to use the preprocessor to switch which namespace was consulted/included.  You could make them run-time values taken from config.  As you say, ifdefs and macros are possible.  You could have some part of your build system specify an os-specific object to link.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight fixed the typo.

Comment: @TonyD I wanted to include more code, but basically it's just valid integer values, so i thought more specifications about  my particular problem would be less helpful for others, so I wanted to keep it general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces ?

```
namespace PLATFORM_A
{
    static int id[4]{200,300,400,500};
}

namespace PLATFORM_B
{
    static int id[4]{500,400,300,200};
}

using namespace USE_PLATFORM;

...

id_vector = std::vector<int> (id,id + (sizeof(id)/sizeof(int)));
```

With `g++ -DUSE_PLATFORM=PLATFORM_A ...` or `g++ -DUSE_PLATFORM=PLATFORM_B ...` or however you setup `USE_PLATFORM`....

Comment: This is closer to what i wanted. But then I thought that it also makes it a little less obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to put different values for different platforms, and you need the change to happen in code (as opposed to, say, a configuration file) you will end up with an `#ifdef` in your code. Here is one example of how you can do it:

```
static int id[4]{
#ifdef PLEFTORM_1
200,300,400,500
#endif
#ifdef PLEFTORM_2
100,200,410,522
#endif
};
id_vector = std::vector<int> (id,id + (sizeof(id)/sizeof(*id)));
```

Another solution may be to put all platform-dependent stuff in separate files, and conditionally include that file. This may reduce the number of `#ifdef`s to 1, but the overall code may end up being harder to read.

Of course you can change your strategy, and place platform-specific IDs in a configuration file. This would help you avoid conditional compilation, at the expense of introducing a run-time dependency on the configuration file.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid... but I guess for something this simple maybe is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> id_vector (id,id + (sizeof(id)/sizeof(int)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id_vector = std::vector<int> (id, id + (sizeof(id)/sizeof(*id)));
```